# Report Builder 3.0 on Surface Pro 4

Tags: reporting-services, report

I have recently been supplied with a Surface Pro 4. I generally use it for emails, browsing and demo-ing my wares either in Excel or Reporting Services.

It is an i7/8GB version and runs SQL Server better than my old laptop. However, I am having some issues with trying to use Report Builder 3.0 on its hi-res display. Initially I had issues with SSMS but found out that I needed a manifest file so that SSMS uses a lower resolution. However I don't seem to be able to resolve the display issues with RB 3.0. Dialog boxes appear tiny, buttons and their text seem overlaid or just missing.

Has anyone else had similar issues or does anyone know how to resolve such issues. I had tried changing the resolution but makes little if any difference. Below is an example screenshot, you can see the Run button is obscured, not sure what the four grey squares are and its super-tiny.

Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running it in compatibility mode?

Comment: I am running it from within the Report Manager browser so not sure how to run it compatibility mode from there. I can try downloading the standalone version and trying that.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from Wes's suggestion about running the program in compatibility mode, I downloaded the standalone program for RB 3.0 and using a program manifest file, I can now use RB 3.0 without any issues or funny screen goings-on.

Thanks all